# How to send a 'GET' request with a lot of data and keep it REST-ful

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

My client app wants to 'GET' a URL with a query argument that is way too long (the server will respond with 413). As I workaround, I modified the server app (I wrote that too) to look for that parameter in the request body (form-encoded) if it doesn't find it in the URL query.

I wrote the client app in Python. It uses the 'requests' lib.  I tried sending a 'GET' with a form-encoded message body:

```
url = 'https://my/server/app/endpoint'
very_long_arg = '.....'
res = CLIENT_SESS.request('GET', url, data={
        'arg': very_long_arg,
    })
```

The server app still returns 413, which means that the 'requests' library must have appended 'arg' to the URL. 
If you wonder why I have to post such a long URL parameter, the argument are pairs of latitude/longitude coordinates and the endpoint returns an static image of a map with the outline of those geo-coordinates drawn over the map  Sometimes there are just a few points but sometimes there are hundreds, and each coordinate can contain over 10 decimal places, so it gets long quite fast.

Has anyone else had this problem?  How did you get around it? Did you have to 'POST' instead? I want to keep the API 'REST-ful' and this endpoint only returns a static image; it does not create anything.

Comment: Unless you have every possible map pregenerated, you *are* creating something; you aren't simply fetching pre-existing images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to send a 'GET' request with a lot of data and keep it REST-ful

There isn't a good answer here; the key problem is that HTTP provides a uniform interface with document store semantics, and what you want is a remote function.  So you've got an impedance mismatch.

What REST wants is resources, and using the resource identifier as a key to fetch a representation of the resource.  Any named information can be a resource, including names like "the answer to my question".  Which is perfectly fine, but in practice the server can't provide a representation of the answer without being told the question.

So the "REST" answer would look something like "create a new resource that is the answer to my question, then get the representation of this resource".  At scale, that's brilliant, because we can use the identifier for this answer to cache the results, and everybody in the world can find out the answer to your question really cheaply.

But... the protocol is kind of clumsy, and those other people still have to discover the identifier for the answer to your question, and so on.  It's a lot of overhead in situations where caching provides no additional value.

What can you try instead?

You can POST - that works, in so far as we strip away all of the useful semantics.  POST doesn't promise safe message handling, nor even idempotent message handline, nor any useful caching behavior.  It's effectively falling back to an RPC call.

You can look in the HTTP method registry for other safe methods that define semantics for the request body.  There aren't very many safe methods, so the search is pretty quick; the only reasonable candidates are REPORT and SEARCH, both of which are coupled to WebDAV semantics.  I've looked at those specifications several times, without ever feeling confident that was a good answer, but your circumstances may be different.

You can look into defining your own method -- new method specifications come from somewhere, after all.  Create a new standard, encourage the vendors to support it, and presto!

You can introduce your own method, without standardizing it.  Not wrong, per se, but not particularly REST -- part of the point of REST is that we do really awesome things using general-purpose components.  If your API needs a bespoke client and caching strategy, then you are starting to stray from the REST ideal.

In practice?  [It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Answer (score 3):

Practicality beats purity. Send a POST.